# Is there a closed formula for $\binom{a}{k}+\binom{b}{k}-\binom{c}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

For integers $c > b > a > k \ge 1$, consider the binomial sum
$$\binom{a}{k}+\binom{b}{k}-\binom{c}{k}.  \tag{$\star$}$$
Does ($\star$) have other closed-form representations?

Comment: I would say that [b]is[/b] a closed form!

Comment: Question edited accordingly.  =)

Comment: You could, of course, use the definition to write this as $\frac{a!}{k!(a- k)!}+ \frac{b!}{k!(b- k)!}- \frac{c!}{k!(c-k)!}= \frac{a!(b-k)!(c-k)!+ b!(a- k)!(c- k)!- c!(a- k)!(b- k)!}{k!(a- k)!(b- k)!(c- k)!}$

Comment: Unlikely to find a better closed form. If $(x)_k$ is the falling factorial polynomial, it is trivially: $$\frac{(a)_k+(b)_k-(c)_k}{k!}.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Recall the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^j$$

Since the expression $\binom{a}{k}+\binom{b}{k}-\binom{c}{k}$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^a+(1+x)^b-(1+x)^c
\end{align*}
any simplification of the binomial coefficients correponds to a simplification of the polynomials, but there is none in sight.